# What does a line over a complex number mean?

Tags: complex-numbers

I understand that $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, but I don't understand what I need to calculate. What is the $w$ with that line above? And is all this a product?

[image]

Comment: it is the complex conjugate if $w=x+iy$ then $\bar{w}=x-iy$. You just change the sign of the imaginary part.

Comment: Imgur reports this image as missing. The OP appears to have enough reputation for an inline image,  so it should be done

Answer (score 4):

$\bar{w}$ denotes the complex conjugate. If $w=x+iy$ then $\bar{w}=x−iy$. You just change the sign of the imaginary part.

$$3jz\bar{w}=3j(-4+3j)(5+2j)$$